# How to convert C variable-length array code to Rust?

Tags: rust, variable-length-array, borrow-checker

I know Rust doesn't support variable-length arrays, but that leaves me wondering what to replace them with, given that:

- I don't want to allocate and deallocate a tiny Vec in a loop
- The borrow checker doesn't let me move the code outside the loop
- There are many limitations on fixed-size arrays, so I can't figure out how to use them

The C code I'm converting processes an image by calling a callback on each line, passing a small array of pointers:

```
float *tmp[img->channels]; // Small, up to 4 elements
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int ch = 0; ch < img->channels; ch++) {
        tmp[ch] = &img->channel[ch]->pixels[width * y];
    }
    callback(tmp, img->channels);
}
```

My Rust attempt ([example in playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0Afn%20callback(rows%3A%20%26%5B%26mut%20%5Bf32%5D%5D)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20img%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20channel%3A%20Vec%3Cchan%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20chan%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pixels%3A%20Option%3CVec%3Cf32%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20height%20%3D%20100%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20width%20%3D%20100%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20img%20%3D%20img%7Bchannel%3AVec%3A%3Anew()%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20y%20in%200..height%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20%26img.channel.iter().map(%7Cchannel%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26mut%20channel.pixels.as_ref().unwrap()%5Bwidth%20*%20y%20..%20width%20*%20(y%2B1)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback(tmp)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable)):

```
for y in 0..height {
    let tmp = &img.channel.iter().map(|channel| {
        &mut channel.pixels.as_ref().unwrap()[width * y .. width * (y+1)]
    }).collect();
    callback(tmp);
}
```

But it's rejected:

> a collection of type `[&mut [f32]]` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&mut [f32]`

Sadly, that sounds exactly like what I was trying to do!

I've tried using a fixed-size array, but Rust doesn't support generics on them, so I can't populate it from an iterator, and I can't populate them in a C-like loop, because references taken in the loop don't outlive it.

> the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&mut [f32]>` is not implemented for the type `[&mut [f32]; 4]`

---

Another approach with taking slice of memory from a fixed-size array, also fails:

```
let mut row_tmp: [&mut [f32]; 4] = unsafe{mem::zeroed()};
for y in 0..height {
    row_tmp[0..channels].iter_mut().zip(img.chan.iter_mut()).map(|(t, chan)| {
        *t = &mut chan.img.as_ref().unwrap()[(width * y) as usize .. (width * (y+1)) as usize]
    });
    cb(&row_tmp[0..channels], y, width, image_data);
}
```

> error: cannot borrow `img.chan` as mutable more than once at a time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`arrayvec`](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) is a library that does what you’re looking for. (Also, you probably want `iter_mut` and `as_mut` instead of `iter` and `as_ref`.)

```
for y in 0..height {
    let tmp: ArrayVec<[_; 4]> = img.channel.iter_mut().map(|channel| {
        &mut channel.pixels.as_mut().unwrap()[width * y .. width * (y+1)]
    }).collect();
    callback(&tmp);
}
```

It allocates a fixed amount of storage (here 4 items) on the stack, and behaves like a `Vec` whose size is bounded (up to the capacity specified at compile time) but variable.

Most of the complexity in `arrayvec` is to deal with running destructors for a variable number of items. But since `&mut _` doesn’t have a destructor, you can also get a way with just a fixed-size array. But you have to use `unsafe` code and be careful not to read un-initialized items. (Fixed-size arrays don’t implement `FromIterator`, which is what `Iterator::collect` uses.)

([Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=429be71d05fd0ced50ad&version=stable))

```
let n_channels = img.channel.len();
for y in 0..height {
    let tmp: [_; 4] = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() }
    for (i, channel) in img.channel.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        tmp[i] = &mut channel.pixels.as_mut().unwrap()[width * y .. width * (y+1)];
    }
    // Careful to only touch initialized items...
    callback(&tmp[..n_channels]);
}
```

**Edit**: The unsafe code can be replaced with:

```
let mut tmp: [&mut [_]; 4] = [&mut [], &mut [], &mut [], &mut []];
```

The shorter `[&mut []; 4]` initializer syntax does not apply here because `&mut [_]` is not implicitly copyable. The type annotation is necessary so you don’t get `[&mut [_; 0]; 4]`.

Comment: This is awesome Simon, props to bluss for creating it!